# Handle Error when sending activation email in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I had written an APIView where the user can register a new account on my website. When the user successfully creates an account, I send them a verified email. The code is below

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=serializer.data.get('email'))

        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        relativeLink = reverse('verify-email')

        absurl = 'http://' + current_site + \
            relativeLink + '?token=' + str(token)

        email_body = 'Hi ' + user.fullname + \
            ' Use link below to verify your email \n' + absurl
        data = {
            'to_email': user.email,
            'email_body': email_body,
            'email_subject': '[GetTheDeal] Verify your email'
        }

        send_email(data)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

But if the `send_email()` had failed. In my cases because I'm using 2-factor auth for my google account. In that scenario, what should I do? because if I don't, I'm getting an error but the account creates successfully, that doesn't make sense to me.

Here is `send_email()` function

```
def send_email(data):
    email = EmailMessage(to=[data['to_email']],
                         subject=data['email_subject'], body=data['email_body'])
    email.send()
```

Comment: what is the smtp your are you using + what does the error say ?

Comment: I know why I get the error. It because I use 2-factor auth for the google account. The error has been fixed but I wonder what if another error occurs. What I have to take to make the system still work in the case that send_email failed

Comment: The development server doesn't make system fail on error, it just handles the exception and goes on, just as production server does. This is the way it's supposed to be – HTTP is stateless, error in one request shouldn't affect the next one.

Comment: @seif  So it's fine to fail on sending an email. The server still has to return information of the user's account that has been registered instead of some error.

Comment: maybe put the send mail function on `try: except:` block and handle when error occurs